# Beacon consensus client lighthouse syncing speed decrease every hour - might take 1+ month to sync fully

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, consensus, full-node, lighthouse

I am installing a full Ethereum node (for geth client only) in VPS Vultr.
Last time, I tried 4 servers with different prices. Because its syncing speed seems very slow so I changed (upgraded with higher prices) the VPS server. Finally, I have stopped at the $500 server in Vultr. Now I am installing the beacon consensus client (lighthouse) to sync with geth client.
When installing the lighthouse, at first the syncing speed was 150slots/s,
After a few hours, it decreased to 80 slots/s -> 40 slots/s and now 20 slots/s, maybe it will decrease to 2 or 3 slots/s, this happens every time when I use any kind of VPS.
Currently, my resource is 64GB RAM, 8CoreCPU, NVME SSD 1TB, 2GB speed for download and upload speed, and 2TB Bandwidth.
I have also tried to set the target peers to 150 and restarted the sync several times to increase the download speed, but it is really slow till now. And continue to decrease.
As you know, at first the estimation is 1 day (when it is 150 slots/s), and now it is 2 days.
And when I wait one day more, it will continue to show 2 days for estimation because the sync speed is 1/2 every time.
How I could fix this? If I should wait like this, it will take a month to sync the full Ethereum node.
Maybe should I use a $5k server? Or is there anything missing for speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syncing a full Ethereum node can be a resource-intensive process, and it's not uncommon for syncing speeds to decrease over time. However, there are a few things you can try to improve the speed:
Increase the number of target peers: Although you mentioned that you've already tried this, it's worth noting that increasing the number of target peers can help improve syncing speed. You can try increasing it further to see if it makes a difference.
Use a faster VPS: You mentioned that you've already tried multiple VPS servers, but it's possible that a faster server could help improve syncing speed. However, it's important to note that there may be diminishing returns as you increase the server's resources.
Use a different syncing client: You mentioned that you're using the Lighthouse client to sync with the Geth client. It's possible that using a different syncing client could help improve syncing speed. For example, you could try using the Parity client instead.
Use a syncing service: If you're still having trouble syncing your node, you could consider using a syncing service like Infura or QuickNode. These services allow you to connect to their nodes, which are already synced with the Ethereum network, and can help you avoid the syncing process altogether.
It's also worth noting that syncing a full Ethereum node can take a significant amount of time, even with optimal conditions. If you're syncing for the first time, it's not uncommon for the process to take several days or even weeks. However, once your node is synced, subsequent syncs should be faster.